# Invoke a camera to start in Drupal 7 Forms API

Tags: 7, forms

I am currently developing a module which must be capable of taking a picture. I dont know how will I make it? How will I invoke a camera to open just by clicking a button? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [webcams module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webcams) ? Even if it's dev I'd say it's worth trying.

Do a [search on webcam on Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/webcam?f[0]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule) and try out some of the modules listed.

Else if you want to develop your own module then the best way is probably doing the integration of an existing webcam jquery module. (See [some jquery plugin examples here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/10/best-jquery-webcam-plugin-example/))

Comment: For webcams you have a dev version for D 7. Do try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Else the Kaltura module has a D 7 release and is actively maintained. Also the Webcam field module has a dev D 7 version. - I'd try them three (webcams, kaltura, webcam field), just to beging with.

Comment: If you are planning on developing your own module I would recommend to watch this basic tutorial on how to created a basic webcam that takes pictures using HTML5 and JavaScript. http://www.tinkernut.com/2013/03/19/html5-photo-booth/